# Inheritance : expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an exception class in C++ and it doesn't work. I've reduced the code to a minimum and I still can't find the error. Here is my header file :

```
#ifndef LISTEXCEPTION_H
#define LISTEXCEPTION_H

// C++ standard libraries
#include <exception>

/* CLASS DEFINITION */
class ListException: public exception {
};

#endif //LISTEXCEPTION_H
```

and here is the error I get :

```
error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

This is quite unexpected. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you mean

```
class ListException: public std::exception
//                          ^^^
```

?

Comment: Thank you !! It was obvious, since I'm in an header file !!

Comment: @Backslash36 In addition to the missing `std::` on `std::exception` problem, you do know that in C++ any class can be an exception?  You don't have to inherit from `std::exception` if you don't want to.

Comment: Oh, I tought it was a requirement. Thank you

Comment: @Backslash36 it's not, but it's recommended.

Comment: @Yakk: You don't have to if you don't want to -- but exception classes should almost always all be derived from one common base.

Comment: @JerryCoffin sure, but there are exceptions to that rule.  And I suspect that Backslash36 is coming from a language where that kind of derivation rule is enforced.

Answer (score 4):

It's subtly telling you that `exception` isn't the name of a class (with a declaration that's in scope, anyway).

You probably intended `std::exception` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`exception` lives in the `std` namespace:

```
class ListException: public std::exception { ... }
```